# Cannot install twitteR package

Tags: r, twitter

Im trying to install the package twitteR in RStudio but I am getting errors with the dependencies of DBI package and so the installation of twitteR isn't completed.

Here is the error....I hope someone can help out.

```r
install.packages("twitteR")

>Installing package into ‘D:/Users/vijhaver/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘DBI’


>  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
    binary source needs_compilation
DBI  0.3.1    0.4             FALSE

>trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/twitteR_1.1.9.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 446779 bytes (436 KB)
downloaded 436 KB

>package ‘twitteR’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

>The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\vijhaver\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpacWdm7\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘DBI’

>trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/DBI_0.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 141460 bytes (138 KB)
downloaded 138 KB

>'D:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"D:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "D:\Users\vijhaver\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\vijhaver\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpacWdm7/downloaded_packages/DBI_0.4.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘DBI’ had non-zero exit status

>The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\vijhaver\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpacWdm7\downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field: title
2: In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field: keyword
3: In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field: alias
```

Comment: Try including the type="win.binary" argument in `install.packages()`: `install.packages("twitteR", type="win.binary")`

Comment: @lmo thanks that worked perfectly :) but what does type="win.binary" do?

Comment: Some packages need to be compiled. This argument tells R to download the windows binary file if one is available.

Comment: @Imo would be good to move this to an answer :)