# Can't install twitteR package in R

Tags: r, twitter, package, social-networking

I'm trying to install the mentioned package, but in the middle of the process the following message shown and the installation fails.

```
package ‘rjson’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 745472 != reported length 769130
2: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
3: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
  cannot open compressed file 'DBI/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

The solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983411/cannot-install-twitter-package) couldn't help, by the way!

Comment: You may want to consider to try the newer package, `rtweet`. Good luck :)

Comment: @mysteRious, thanks! but since I'm following a tutorial that uses that package, is there any way to install it properly?

Answer (score 1):

You have not shown us "HOW" you tried installing pkg-twitteR but from the fact that it tried to install an additional package, I'm guessing you used dependencies=TRUE in the `install.packages`-command. (I pretty much always use that parameter, so i'm not criticizing that strategy.)  In any case you *should* now (and always) edit your question to include the exact command or actions you used. You should also include details of your OS and R versions. The missing item appears to be in the "DBI"-package, so I would try:

```
install.packages("DBI", dependencies=TRUE)
```

And then retry to install. The installation process sometimes fails when dependencies of dependencies are not met.